# Change config in ckeditor for line break

Tags: javascript, jquery, ckeditor, ckeditor.net

I wanted to have

```
config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
```

I am referencing editor directly form CDN

I tried it this way

```
@Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.About, new { @class = "form-control", @id = "About" })
                <script>
                    CKEDITOR.replace('About');
                    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
                        config.enterMode = CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR;
                    };
                </script>
```

Thanks

Comment: its would be better if I know the reason of downvote, so I dont repeat it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loading CKEditor from CDN does not prevent you from providing a custom configuration.

See the following resources:

- The [CKEditor CDN site](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/) itself!
- The [Setting CKEditor Configuration](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_configuration) article which descibes how and where you can provide the editor configuration.
- Any of the samples from [CKEditor SDK](http://sdk.ckeditor.com/) - scroll down to the "Get Sample Source Code" to see the entire code needed to generate this exact configuration, with CKEditor loaded from CDN.

Example for an in-page configuration (so for the CKEditor instance with `id` of `About`):

```
<script>
    CKEDITOR.replace( 'About', {
        enterMode: CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR
    } );
</script>
```

By the way, [using `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` is actually unrecommended](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_best_practices-section-use-enter-mode-p), especially if you want to use it just to change paragraph spacing.

Comment: Unless you tell us more how you tried to change it and where it's impossible it say why it's not working...

Comment: please check the question edits

Comment: Like I said, setting `enterMode` to `CKEDITOR.ENTER_BR` is not a correct way to change paragraph spacing and it can bring undesired consequences. CKEditor and all its features are optimized to work with the default `CKEDITOR.ENTER_P` setting.

If you do it to control paragraph spacing, you should use stylesheets instead. Set up a suitable margin value for `<p>` elements, for example: `p { margin: 0; }` and add it to your configuration with the [`config.contentsCss`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-contentsCss) setting.

Comment: The same way as Anna Tomanek showed you how to change `enterMode`. Just point to some stylesheet.

Comment: And please finally read what's written on [CKEditor CDN site](http://cdn.ckeditor.com/). Everything is there!

Comment: Don't expect that anyone will spend time on giving you the answers if you can't spend time reading the docs (on which someone else already spent time writing them). You even didn't care about writing a clear question... StackOverflow definitely isn't for people with approach like yours.

Comment: I dont want anyone to go over, if anyone already have then I was asking, what is not clear in the question? would you clear more, and is StackOverflow only for answers?